# Move Paragraph With a Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following paragraph:

```
<p id="paragraph">
  <u>
    My First Paragraph
  </u>
</p>
```

Then, I have a button with `onclick` function. I want it to move the paragraph to the center. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "center"? Margin-wise? Vertical center? In front of text?

Comment: I mean center horizontally

Comment: Oh, so like the text alignment? Then you would use text-align:center

Comment: How can I do that with a button?

Comment: @NathanChan — Styling things to be in the centre is very basic stuff. Changing styles with JS is very basic stuff. Doing things when buttons are clicked with JS is very basic stuff. Your question shows no evidence of any of those things. You need to do a basic among of research before resorting to Stackoverflow. It sounds like you should be starting with an introductory level JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: @NathanChan I've answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function centerThis() {
  document.getElementById("paragraph").style.textAlign = "center";
}
```

```css
#paragraph {
  text-align:left;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">
  <u>
    My First Paragraph
  </u>
</p>

<button onclick="centerThis()">Click me</button>
```

As you can see, when the button is clicked, the method centerThis() is called, and the paragraph is centered. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_textalign.asp for more information. I would recommend reading about DOM manipulation.

Comment: Np! I'm glad I could help. Happy New Year!